Common error code and error response description in jmeter to table format
Is there a Jmeter plugin or utility to read the JMeter failure log for an application?
For instance, if I have 10 APIs with different transaction names, my requirement is to generate a table that indicates the number of failures for each transaction based on the HTTP response codes. The table should include the count of failures, the HTTP status code (such as 500), and a description of the failure. This should be separated by each response code, providing a count and description for each.
This will help me identify the failure count and the reasons for the failures efficiently.


JMeter .jtl result files are CSV files so you can create a table in Excel or equivalent spreadsheet processing application

HTML Reporting Dashboard has the table which is pretty much close to your requirements


Aggregate Report listener provides the table which is pretty much close to your requirements:


There is possibility to use Backend Listener to send results to InfluxDB or similar time-series database and then you can come up with Grafana dashboard containing whatever table you want



response body has max similar text, but ends with some UUID. unable to make the difference.
currently using notepad++ to find the common error types. but want to automate this manual process.
Say suppose if the errors are 10K. i have valiadate atleast 50 times minimum to see what different errors i have and similar error it belong to.
